# Не работает ввод с клавиатуры, после вызова резидентной программы, перехватывающий ввод с клавиатуры(assembler,dos)

Tags: ассемблер, dos

```
  .model tiny            
.CODE        
org 100h
.386  
start:    
jmp install_handler 


str db "hello world",0dh,0ah,'$'  
    db 0eah
    old_int dd ?

int_handler proc far  
    pushf         
    call old_int
    pusha  
    push es
    push ds
    push cs
    pop ds   
push 0B800h
pop es   
mov si,19h
mov bx,0
str_search:

mov cx,50h      
mov di,0
search_scobok:  
    mov al,07h
    mov es:[bx+1],al
    mov al,28h
    cmp es:[bx],al
    jne not_28h

        push bx     
        inc di

    not_28h:
  
    mov al,29h
    cmp es:[bx],al
    jne not_29h

        cmp di,0
        je wrong_29h
        pop ax
        dec di
        jmp not_29h

        wrong_29h:
        mov al,1Dh
        mov es:[bx+1],al
        
    not_29h:
    add bx,2
loop search_scobok  
mov cx,di    

cmp di,0
je no_wrong_28h
mov dx,bx
paint_28h:
    pop bx
    mov al,1Dh
    mov es:[bx+1],al
loop paint_28h
mov bx,dx
no_wrong_28h:   
sub si,1
cmp si,0
jne str_search
    pop ds
    pop es
    popa
    IRET
int_handler endp
 


install_handler:  
    mov ax,3509h
    int 21h    ;get vect
    mov word ptr old_int,bx
    mov word ptr old_int + 2,es

    mov dx,offset int_handler
    mov ax,2509h
    int 21h      ;set vect
    
    
    ;mov ax,3100h
    ;mov dx,(install_handler - start + 10Fh)/16
    ;mov dx,0FFFFh/16
    ;int 21h      ;stay resident
    mov ah,49h
    mov es,ds:[2Ch]
    int 21h
    lea dx,install_handler
    int 27h
end start
```

После запуска программы, ввод просто не работает. Не могу понять что я делаю не так. Программа проверяет правильность растановки скобок ( )

Comment: Может поделитесь с общественностью, что делает обработчик вашего резидента и что вы от него ожидаете? В большинстве случаях, для перехвата клавиатуры лучше подменять не `INT-09h`, а `INT-15h AH=4fh`, поскольку первое является аппаратным прерыванием и к нему больше требований. Описание INT-15h можно найти здесь: http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_026.6.html

Answer (score 0):

1. При нажатии клавиши, клавиатура генерит аппаратное прерывание `IRQ-1`, которое поступает в контролёр APIC. Теперь, посредством сигнала `INTR` (Request) APIC доставляет IRQ и связанный с ним вектор(9) - в процессор, на что CPU отвечает контролёру сигналом подтверждения `INTA` (Acknowledgment). Далее, CPU передаёт управление по вектору `int-9h`, обработчик которого просто считывает с порта(60h) клавиатуры скан-код нажатой клавиши, и записывает его в память кольцевой очереди клавиатуры. Теперь прерывание `int-16h` извлекает клавишу из очереди, и добавив к скан-коду ascii - вручает его пользовательскому запросу. Таким образом получаем выстроенную по приоритету цепочку: `IRQ-1 --> int-9h --> int-16h`.
2. Фишка в том, что на машинах АТ, `int-9h` передаёт управление в `int-15h` (расширенный сервис), который и помещает скан-код в клавиатурную очередь. Этот сервис имеет довольно внушительный список функций, и только его `AH=4Fh` отвечает за клавиатуру. По сути, функция была введена специально для того, чтобы пользователь не перехватывал аппаратный `int-9h`, а воспользовались услугами более безобидного программного `int-15h`. Основное требование - если обработчик что-нибудь меняет, то на выходе должен сбросить флаг(CF) в нуль. Вот пример резидента, который парсит клавиатурный ввод:

```
;// FASM-code
;//------------
org  100h
jmp  @setup                      ;// уходим на перехват..

old15h:  dw    0,0               ;// место под оригинальный вектор

;// Новый обработчик прерывания INT-15h
;//-------------------------------------
new15h:  pushf                   ;// флаги в стек
         cmp   ah,4Fh            ;// это сервис клавиатуры?
         jе    @keyb             ;// если да
         call  far [cs:old15h]   ;// иначе: зовём оригинальный обработчик,
         iret                    ;//  ..и возврат управления системе.

@keyb:   ;//<----- значит была нажата клавиша!
         ;//<----- её скан-код лежит в регистре AL

;//***************************************
;//***** ЗДЕСЬ ОБРАБАТЫВАЕМ ВВОД *********
;//******* НА СВОЁ УСМОТРЕНИЕ ************
;//***************************************

         popf                    ;// восстановить флаги,
         clc                     ;//  ..и среди них сбросить CF=0.
         retf  2                 ;// выйти из обработчика

;// Инициализация резидента TSR
;//-------------------------------------
@setup:  push  es               ;// (+) AH=35h портит регистр ES
         mov   ax,3515h         ;// читаем вектор(15) из таблицы IVT
         int   21h              ;// ES:BX = результат
         mov   [old15h],bx      ;// запомним его смещение,
         mov   [old15h+2],es    ;// ..и сегмент.
         pop   es               ;// (-)

         mov   ax,2515h         ;// перехват прерывания(15)
         mov   dx,new15h        ;// CS:DX = адрес нового обработчика
         int   21h              ;//
         mov   dx,@setup        ;// всё-что выше метки "@setup",
         int   27h              ;// ..останется в памяти как резидент.
```